# How to remove duplicates from object list based on that object property in c#

Tags: c#

I've got a problem with removing duplicates at runtime from my list of object.

I would like to remove duplicates from my list of object and then set counter=counter+1 of base object.

```
public class MyObject 
{
   MyObject(string name) 
   {
      this.counter = 0;
      this.name = name;
   }
   public string name;
   public int counter;
}

List<MyObject> objects_list = new List<MyObject>();
objects_list.Add(new MyObject("john"));
objects_list.Add(new MyObject("anna"));
objects_list.Add(new MyObject("john"));
foreach (MyObject my_object in objects_list) 
{
    foreach (MyObject my_second_object in objects_list) 
    {
        if (my_object.name == my_second_object.name) 
        {
           my_object.counter = my_object.counter + 1;
           objects_list.remove(my_second_object);
        }
    }
}
```

It return an error, because objects_list is modified at runtime. How can I get this working?

Comment: do a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` and go backwards. this way when you remove an element you can still move up the list

Comment: If you want to mofify the elemnts in a list while iterating that list, use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: You are by the way comparing object to object.name, which makes no sense and cannot compile, I guess just a mistype?

Comment: I can't just use for, because during delete the iterator will change. Also I can't make two backwards for, because I will get the same error.

Comment: You can't use foreach either to iterate a collection that you change

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking this question. In some other languages it's possible, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: you could make a new temporary list, and add the items to this second list while checking that they aren't already in the second list, and then replace the original list with the temporary list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer seem to be correct, though I think it will do scan of the whole list twice, depending on your requirement this might or might not be good enough. Here is how you can do it in one go:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
foreach(var obj in objects_list) 
{
  if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(obj.name)
  {
    dictionary[obj.name] = obj;
    obj.counter++;
  }
  else
  {
      dictionary[obj.name].counter++;
  } 
}
```

Then dictionary.Values will contain your collection

Comment: That also won´t give number of dupes.

Comment: Well, the example is simplified, but list can contain 100 000 records :/

Comment: Not sure which number of dupes OP wanted: the one I counted or the number of "uniqeq" dupes

Comment: Then you'll need to create a dictionary

Comment: Just count of the same names. If list contains MyObject with name "anna" counter at the end should be 1, if list contains two MyObject with names "john" counter at the end should be 2. I think it's clear.

Comment: I have misunderstood the question a bit it seems, but the other answer seem to be perfectly fine even though it will be double scan I think, so not the fastest again

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Please just correct line dictionary.Add(obj) to dictionary.Add(obj.name, obj);

Comment: Have fixed it, thx, it's equivalent to dictionary.Add(obj.name, obj);

Answer (score 1):

With a help of *Linq* `GroupBy` we can combine duplicates in a *single group* and process it (i.e. return an item which represents all the duplicates):

```
 List<MyObject> objects_list = ...

 objects_list = objects_list
   .GroupBy(item => item.name)            
   .Select(group => {                            // given a group of duplicates we
      var item = group.First();                  // - take the 1st item
      item.counter = group.Sum(g => g.counter);  // - update its counter
      return item;                               // - and return it instead of group
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: With a little bit change it works: item.counter = group.Sum(g => g.counter + 1); but as far I'm not from C# and it looks a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: Actually it should work if you just write `item.counter = group.Count()`. You will get the number of same names in each group (you might want to subtract one if that's what you want)